# How do I use ajax GET to submit form data to correct URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have an HTML page which is

```
<form id="customer">    
<label for="customer-name">Enter customer names: </label>
<input type="text" id="customer-name"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

This HTML page's URL is `http://www.example.com/customer`. When I submit the form, I want to use ajax GET to the following URL:

```
http://www.example.com/customer/query?customer-name=davis
```

The ajax code is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#customer").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'customer/query',
        type: 'GET',
        data: $("#customer-name").val(),
        success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        }
    });
    });
});
```

But when I entered "davis" in the textbox and clicked the "Submit" button, it went to the following URL (without `/query` subpath):

```
http://www.example.com/customer?customer-name=davis
```

So it didn't go to the correct URL address that I want. Even though I specified the URL in the Ajax request, it only goes to `/customer` path, not `/customer/query` subpath. How can I make the ajax GET to the correct URL address? Or am I making some mistakes in the code?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking node, not jquery when answering ;)

Comment: I did change my answer, though, but don't feel like undeleting ;)

Comment: So how do I change the `url` part in the ajax request? Thanks.

Comment: Change to `$("#customer").submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: Oh wait, your problem is that it still submits the form the usual way...

Comment: @mplungjan, that looks more like an answer, not comment ;)

Comment: @mplungjan: I tried it but doesn't work. It still goes to `customer` URL which is the current page, not `customer/query` URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is likely submitting. Try this

```
$(function() {
  $("#customer").submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $.get('customer/query',{"customer-name":$("#customer-name").val()},
       function(data) {
        alert(data);
       }
     );
  });
});
```

The above code is used to get data from the server without loading a new page into the browser.

From what I understand you want to remove all your javascript and simply change to

```
<form action="customer/query"> 
  <label for="customer-name">Enter customer names: </label>
  <input type="text" id="customer-name" name="customer-name"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I get to the URL `http://www.example.com/customer/query?customer-name=davis` after I submit the form? Right now it's only poping up an alert message box.

Comment: The alert is the result of the submission to your server, you do not want Ajax if you want to GO.to the URL, then you just put the URL in an action attribute in the form

Comment: Yes, that's right. So what to do if I want to redirect to the above URL with query string part after I submit the form? Currently it only stays at the URL which is `http://www.example.com/customer` after I submit the form.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I want! Actually I misunderstand what Ajax does for us: Updating the current page without loading a new page. Since I want to redirect to the new URL with query string, I shouldn't use Ajax at the first place. Thanks for your help.